# Filter Sentinel-2 Image Collection for many tiles

Tags: google-earth-engine

I used the code snippet below to filter a Sentinel-2 S2_SR collection by metadata (S-2 Tile). 
This snippet helped me to obtain imagery that covers the Tile 32UQC.
Now I would like to get a Sentinel-2 Collection for the following Tiles:

- 32UPU
- 32UPV
- 32UQU
- 32UQV
- 33UUP
- 33UUQ

Does anyone know how to deal with this task? Or should I repeat the `<Collection>.filterMetadata` method for every Tile I listed above?

```
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// Finding images in the Sentinel2 L2A Collection 
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

var s2_2018_03_01TO2018_03_31 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
  .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'equals', '32UQC')
  .filterDate('2018-03-01', '2018-03-31')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 50));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an `ee.Filter.inList()` filter.

```
var tiles = ['32UQC', '32UPU', '32UPV', '32UQU', '32UQV', '33UUP', '33UUQ']
var s2_2018_03_01TO2018_03_31 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('MGRS_TILE', tiles))
  .filterDate('2018-03-01', '2018-03-31')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 50));
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! It worked!